# PyGame Installation Mac

Tags: pygame

I am trying to install pyGame but have no idea what to do. I have tried looking at other posts but none have worked for me. Does anyone have any idea of a simple way to successfully download pyGame?

Thanks

Comment: what did you try? On Linux you have to only use `pip install pygame`. You can also check on official page pygame.org: https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted#Pygame%20Installation

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and type in `pip install pygame`. If this doesnt work it means that you havent decided to add pip (pythons personal internal installer) to your computer and this needs to be added/updated to the newest version